# How to use JUnit TemporaryFolder @Rule with Spring @Value properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

Can I generate a `TemporaryFolder` in a `junit` test, and use that folder as prefix for a `@Value` property?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest {
    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder tmp = new TemporaryFolder();


    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void test()  {
        //TODO how to rewrite the application property with the tmp folder created?
        service.run();
    }
}

@Service
public class MyService {
    @Value("${my.export.path}")
    private String path;

    public void run() {
        //generates a file and exports it to @Value path
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
my.export.path=/var/www/export.csv
```

I want to set the export path to the generated tmp folder of course. But how?

Answer (score 2):

I could solve it with a `@ClassRule` and `ApplicationContextInitializer` rewriting the property in the `ApplicationContext`. While it works, there might be better solutions that I'm still interested in!

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = TemporaryFolderInitializer.class)
public class MyTest {
    @ClassRule
    public static TemporaryFolder tmp = new TemporaryFolder();

    public static class TemporaryFolderInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(applicationContext, "my.export.path=" + tmp.getRoot().getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to inject the value to `path` via setter (but this imposes change of class under test) or via Spring's `ReflectionTestUtils` like this:

```java
@Test
public void test() {
  ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "path", tmp.getRoot().getAbsolutePath());
  service.run();
}
```

You could also think about creating an inner configuration class that is giving you a bean of `MyService` with desired path.